# Skip all the test instead of decorating each test function with @pytest.mark.skipif()?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest file which requires environment being set. So I add the following decorator on every function.

```
@pytest.mark.skipif('password' not in os.environ,
                    reason='Environment variable "password" not set.')
def test_1(mock):
    ....

@pytest.mark.skipif('password' not in os.environ,
                    reason='Environment variable "password" not set.')
def test_2(mock):
    ....

@pytest.mark.skipif('password' not in os.environ,
                    reason='Environment variable "password" not set.')
def test_3(mock):
    ....
```

Is it a way to skip all the test instead of decorating each test function?

BTW, it just skip the tests with the following message. Is it a way to display a warning information of missing environment variable?

```
====== 25 skipped in 5.96s =======
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, you could put all the functions in a class and then mark the class. Wouldn't it make more sense to just have a good testing environment? If your situation is just wanting to do some local testing of the stuff you are developing (which isn't environment dependent), you could probably just use a run command that targets your specific test files/functions.

Comment: I read someone said just using functions for pytest is more pythonic way? What's good "testing environment"? Will try putting all these test functions in a class. The doc page of pytest website uses functions as example. Will need to figure out how to use `@pytest.fixture` for the class way.

Comment: BTW you can create a shorter decorator by putting everything behind the `@` into a variable.

Comment: @ca9163d9 its true, using many of the features of classes can be detrimental yo your tests, but using classes just as a tool for grouping your tests can be really useful. The pytest docs have a section on that at https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a fixture with `autouse=True` that does the skipping for you:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_if_no_password():
    if 'password' in os.environ:
        yield
    else:
        pytest.skip('Environment variable "password" not set.')
```

Another possibility is to put the tests into a class and put the marker on the class instead, as mentioned by Luke Nelson in the comments.